# Performing (string/list) prediction in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, statistics, prediction

I need to perform some type of prediction/suggestion using Python.

For example lets assume that we have multiple lists

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c"]

other_alphabet = ["a", "b", "d"]

another_alphabet = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

there is also a current alphabet under construction

```
current_alphabet = ["a", "b", ...]
```

In 2 of 3 alphabets the letter after `"a", "b"` is `"c"`, so I want the code to predict/suggest that in the `current_alphabet` the next letter following `"a", "b"` will be `"c"` (with 66% probability)

I think the task is a bit more complicated than it looks.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved? Maybe something similar that can help in this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools

alphabet = ["a", "b", "c"]
other_alphabet = ["a", "b", "d"]
another_alphabet = ["a", "b", "c"]

# here we take the nth char of each alphabet that is used as prediction
# (this position is indicated by the number of the currently entered char)
# zip takes the lists, and well, zips :) them, it means it creates new lists, so every
# first elements end up together, second elemends are together and so on.
# as far as current position you have to track it when user enters data (you have to
# know which (first, second, tenth) letter user is entering
current_position=1

letters = zip(alphabet,other_alphabet, another_alphabet)[current_position]
letters = list(letters)
letters.sort()
print 'letters at current position', letters

# here we group all occurences of the same letters,  
letter_groups = itertools.groupby(letters, key=lambda x: x[0])

# here we count the number of occurences of each letter
# from the alphabets, and divide it by the lenght
# of the list of letters

letter_probabilities = [[a[0], sum (1 for _ in a[1])/float(len(letters))] for a in letter_groups]
print 'letter probablilities at the current postion ', letter_probabilities
```

the code above produces following output:

```
letters at current position ['c', 'c', 'd']
letter probablilities at the current postion  [['c', 0.6666666666666666], ['d', 0.3333333333333333]]
```

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but I am not that of a advanced python user so I have some questions about your answer. First of all, does itertools work with python 2.7? could you please comment out the lines of your answer, since I don't have `current_position` and `my_str` variables in my code, I fail to understand what the code does :(

Comment: I added some comments and corrected mistake with my_str, If you have any questions feel free to ask

Comment: thanks for the extra effort.
When I print `letter_probabilities` i get `[['c', 0.3333333333333333], ['d', 0.3333333333333333], ['c', 0.3333333333333333]]`. According to your comments the code should return only letters `c` and `d` with `c` = 66% and `d` = 33%.
I am struggling a bit with understanding your code that is why I base this question on your written comments

Comment: you're right I forgot that you have to sort the list before grouping, now it should work as expected